# Why I can't reference to WITH expression more than one time?

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server I can't reference to `WITH` expression more than one time?

```
DECLARE @total FLOAT;

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.plate, SUM(s.net) AS tonnage
    FROM scale s
    GROUP BY s.plate
)
SELECT @total = SUM(tonnage) / 100 FROM cte;
SELECT t.*, t.tonnage / @total AS percentage FROM cte t;
```

Comment: Because the CTE are defined in the SQL:1999 standard as **for one following statement only**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

> This is derived from a simple query and defined within the execution
>   scope of a **single** SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

CTE is expression which will be disposed after first statement was executed, and will be unavailable after that

And in your case you have to query `Scale` table twice for calculating a total sum

```
DECLARE @Total DECIMAL(19,4) = (SELECT SUM(Net)/100.0 FROM Scales)

SELECT s.PlateID
, SUM(s.Net) AS Tonnage
, SUM(s.Net)/@Total AS Percentage
FROM Scales s
GROUP BY s.PlateID
```

Answer (score 1):

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query.

So you can try something like this and you are missing `Group by` in query

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT s.plate,
                Sum(s.net) AS tonnage
         FROM   scale s
         GROUP  BY s.plate)
SELECT t.plate,
       t.tonnage / ( Sum(tonnage) / 100.0 ) AS percentage,
       Sum(tonnage) / 100.0                 AS total
FROM   cte t
Group by plate
```

Answer (score 1):

Because execution scope of a **CTE** is for a **single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement**. I think you should go for this...

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT s.plate, SUM(s.net) AS tonnage
    FROM scale s
    GROUP BY s.plate
)
SELECT t.*,
       t.tonnage / ( Sum(tonnage) / 100.0 ) AS percentage
FROM   cte t;
```

Comment: Not valid. Did you mean to use `over`?